# SQLite get the 12th record - most efficient?

Tags: sql, sqlite

What's the best SQL query in SQLite to get the Nth item from a list of data.

The data does not have numeric keys

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite3 (or general SQL) retrieve nth row of a query result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419626/sqlite3-or-general-sql-retrieve-nth-row-of-a-query-result)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want OFFSET.

```
SELECT mycol FROM mytable ORDER BY mycol LIMIT 1 OFFSET 11;
```

Shorthand version:

```
SELECT mycol FROM mytable ORDER BY mycol LIMIT 11,1;
```

[Link to documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) which describes OFFSET as follows:

> The optional OFFSET following LIMIT
>   specifies how many rows to skip at the
>   beginning of the result set.

Answer (score 3):

So, say your query was

```
SELECT * from myTable
ORDER BY someField
```

You could use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` to

```
SELECT * from myTable
ORDER BY someField
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 11
```

I'm looking at [this documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) to get that. I think that limits you to one result, skipping the first 11 rows.

Answer (score 1):

Use this if you don't know any field types you can sort by, then loop to the last record:

```
select * from table limit 12
```

If there is a field that will put the table in order, this should get you the 12th record:

```
select * from table where field = (select field from table order by field desc limit 12) limit 1
```

**EDIT**: This is SqLite 2.x syntax before OFFSET was introduced. (The last version I used.)