# SQLite3 (or general SQL) retrieve nth row of a query result

Tags: sql, mysql, sqlite

Quicky question on `SQLite3` (may as well be general `SQLite`)

How can one retrieve the n-th row of a query result?

`row_id` (or whichever index) won't work on my case, given that the tables contain a column with a number. Based on some data, the query needs the data unsorted or sorted by `asc`/`desc` criteria.

But I may need to quickly retrieve, say, rows 2 & 5 of the results.

So other than implementing a `sqlite3_step()==SQLITE_ROW` with a counter, right now I have no idea on how to proceed with this.

And I don't like this solution very much because of performance issues.
So, if anyone can drop a hint that'd be highly appreciated.

Regards
david

Comment: multiple: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492703/sql-how-to-select-1st-3rd-11th-and-nth-row-from-a-table

Answer (score 37, accepted):

add `LIMIT 1` and `OFFSET <n>` to the query
example `SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 1 OFFSET 5132;`

Comment: sounds great but i don't know if this works on sqlite3, will try it out tough

Comment: Is it a zero based index?

Comment: It is like it is zero indexed into what the query would be if you didn't use limit.  If you want to start at the 3rd row then the offset is 2: "SELECT * FROM tableName LIMIT 3 OFFSET 2"  ... this can also be written in reverse order using slightly more compact syntax as in this stack answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325515/sqlite-limit-offset-query

Answer (score 1):

> But I may need to quickly retrieve, say, rows 2 & 5 of the results.

In scenario when you need non-continuous rows you could use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS rn --OVER(ORDER BY ...) --if specific order is required
  FROM t
)
SELECT c 
FROM cte
WHERE rn IN (2,5);  -- row nums
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=b34919cbee03bc952ac0219626b6b8b5)**

Answer (score 0):

The general approach is that, if you want only the nth row of m rows, use an appropriate `where` condition to only get **that** row.

If you need to get to a row and can't because no `where` criteria can get you there, your database has a serious design issue. It fails the [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), which states that "There's no top-to-bottom ordering to the rows."

Comment: but I won't have a criteria for WHERE? row_id's won't work here

Comment: Then how do you know you need the nth row, and not the others?