# SQL: How to select 1st, 3rd, 11th and nth row from a table?

Tags: sql, mysql, sqlite, select

How to select 1st, 3rd, 11th and nth row from a table?

Comment: Some additional info would be helpful.  Does the table have a primary key that is properly seeded?  If so that is all you need to use.

Comment: And you need it to work in both sqllite and mysql? If not which one?

Comment: keep in mind, this is not a talk about best practices, the reason for this type of selection is not for a list.

Comment: just one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419626/sqlite3-or-general-sql-retrieve-nth-row-of-a-query-result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a primary key defined for the table that is an integer based data type--both MySQL and SQLite have auto_increment for example--then you can use:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM TABLE t
 WHERE t.id IN (1,3, 11)
```

...where `id` is the auto_increment column.

There's very little detail to go on, but MySQL and SQLite do not have analytic query support, making queries rather complicated:

```
SELECT y.*
  FROM (SELECT t.*,
                        (SELECT COUNT(*)
                            FROM TABLE x
                           WHERE x.col <= t.col) AS rank
               FROM TABLE t) y
 WHERE y.rank IN (1, 3, 11)
```

Comment: haven't checked on actual server, but I get the idea behind it and that there is no select separate row support in mysql or sqlite.
this answer has both answer + alternative option.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should never ever rely on the order of the rows in your database. Rows have no natural ordering. However, you can add an attribute (unsigned int with auto increment, for instance) which indicates the order of the rows. Be sure that whenever the table is edited, the field is updated accordingly.

You can now select the first, third and eleventh row

```
SELECT * FROM table t
WHERE t.order IN (1, 3, 11)
ORDER BY t.order ASC;
```

Answer (score 2):

For MySQL

```
SET @rows_count = NULL;

select col_list,rn from 
(
    select col_list, @rows_count := IFNULL(@rows_count, 0) + 1 as rn
    from table_name
    order by col_list
    limit 11) top_n
WHERE rn IN (1,3,11)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
Select * 
From ( Select Row_Number() OVER (Order by empno) rno, 
       e.* From scott.emp e )
Where rno in (1, 3, 11)
```