# Removing List Item and then querying database throws exception

Tags: android, database, android-arrayadapter, listactivity

I've converted a list project from a BaseAdapter to an ArrayAdapter ListActivity because I was told in another question that ArrayAdapter was more dynamic and better at, specifically, allowing an item to be removed from the list and then updating to reflect that removal. I'm still running into the same issue with my ArrayAdapter, though, as follows:

I get my list data as so:

```
public void loadAdapter(){

    DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(ActivityMain.this);
    database = helper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor data = database.query("list_data", fields, null, null, null,
            null, null);
    Integer tindex = data.getColumnIndex("listTitle");
    Integer iindex = data.getColumnIndex("listType");

    itemCount = 0;
    for (data.moveToFirst(); !data.isAfterLast(); data.moveToNext()) {
        m_parts.add(new Item(data.getString(tindex), data.getString(iindex)));
        itemCount++;
    }

    data.close();

    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        m_parts.add(new Item("", "R"));
    }

    m_adapter = new ItemAdapter(ActivityMain.this, R.layout.listview, m_parts);

    setListAdapter(m_adapter);  
}
```

with this custom adapter:

```
public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    private ArrayList<Item> objects;

    public ItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<Item> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, null);
        }

        Item i = objects.get(position);

        if (i != null) {

            TextView textview = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_main);
            ImageView imageview = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_main);
            TextView textview2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_main2);
            textview.setText(i.getText());
            textview2.setText(i.getText());

            imageview.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            Integer theDrawable;
            if (i.getImage() != "L") {
                theDrawable = R.drawable.listview_regular;
            } else {
                theDrawable = R.drawable.listview_location;
            }
            imageview.setImageResource(theDrawable);

        }

        v.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
        v.setOnLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(position));
        return v;

    }
}
```

The context menu from longclicklistener offers a delete option, which uses this

```
private void showDialogOnLongClick(final int position) {

 Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

 ArrayList<String> listInfo = getListInfo(position);
 String content = listInfo.get(1);
 String numItems = "";

 if (content != null && content.indexOf("|~|") > -1) {
 String[] contentSplit = content.split("\\|\\~\\|");
 numItems = contentSplit.length + " items in list";
 } else {
 numItems = "No items in list";
 }

 String listTitle = listInfo.get(0);
 String created = "Created: " + listInfo.get(2);
 String modified = "Modified: " + listInfo.get(3);
 String delete = "Delete";
 String edit = "Edit";
 final String[] items = new String[] { created, modified, numItems,
 delete, edit };

 alert.setTitle(listTitle);

 alert.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
 switch (which) {

 case 3:
 if (deleteList(position)) {
//listview.invalidate();
//Item itemToRemove = m_parts.remove(position);
//m_adapter.remove(itemToRemove);
//m_adapter.remove(toRemove);
//m_adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();     <-- These are all things I've tried
//m_adapter.clear();                                in various combinations
//m_adapter.remove(position);

Item toRemove = m_adapter.getItem(position);
m_parts.remove(toRemove); //or, m_parts.remove(position);<-This is what should work
     m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     loadAdapter();
//       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
//      public void run() {
//          m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();     <--I've tried a thread approach
//              }  
//          }); 
 }
 break;

 case 4:
 Intent i = new Intent(ActivityMain.this,
 ShowARegularList.class);
 i.putExtra("list_id", (position + 1) + "");
 startActivity(i);
 break;
 }
 }
 });

 alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

 dialog.dismiss();

 }
 });

 alert.show();
 }
```

which, in case 3 changes the database with

```
// Delete single list item data
public boolean deleteList(int id) {
    id++;
    DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    database = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    // ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    // values.put("_id", id);

    database.delete("list_data", "_id =" + id, null);
    database.close();

    // text = text.removeElementStr();
    // itemCount--;
    return true;

}
```

The above works to remove an item from the list, and closes the gap visually. But, when clicking on the "old" spot from which the item was removed (which raises a new intent to edit the selected item), an exception is raised in the new activity on querying the db (last line, 97 in logcat):

```
final Integer thisListID = Integer.parseInt(listIDstr);
    final DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    database = helper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = database.query("list_data", new String[] { "listTitle",
            "listContent", "dateCreated", "dateModified" }, "_id = " + thisListID
            + "", null, null, null, null);

    ArrayList<String> listInfo = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        listInfo.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("listTitle")));
        listInfo.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("listContent")));
        listInfo.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("dateCreated")));
        listInfo.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("dateModified")));
    }

    cursor.close();
    strListContent = listInfo.get(1).trim();
```

with logcat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity... 
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2049)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2083)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1233)
...
at com.baked.listanywhere.ShowARegularList.onCreate(ShowARegularList.java:97)
```

The list items with index less than the deleted one are fine; those with greater index are one off in their contents. I suspect an error in logic on my part in the query, querying an index that is no longer there...but it seems I should be able to redraw the list and have an index list that mirrors the database. What I would truly like to do is extinguish any memory of the list and then refill it, but I can't seem to do this...any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: My thoughts at this point: as I'm querying with a primary key that no longer exists--can I instead query with rownum (hasn't worked); or create a temp table, load the values into it, and retrieve the nth row...seems like a kludge; any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as no one is chiming in, I've resolved the issue by querying

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM list_data ORDER BY _id LIMIT 1 OFFSET '"+ thisListID +"'", null);
```

thanks to Wojtek at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419626/sqlite3-or-general-sql-retrieve-nth-row-of-a-query-result). And, yes,

```
case 3:
 if (deleteList(position)) {

     Item toRemove = m_adapter.getItem(position);
     m_parts.remove(toRemove);
     m_adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();

     loadAdapter();

 break;
 }
```

was working fine, even though I could have sworn that was the issue!